# Value of series resistor for crystal oscillation

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, resistors, oscillator, crystal

In this [device](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/KSZ9897S-Data-Sheet-DS00002394C.pdf), this is the [Hardware Design Checklist](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ989x-KSZ956x-KSZ9477-Hardware-Design-Checklist-00004151.pdf).

On page 8 of this checklist, section 4.2., it recommends adding a series resistor at the clock out pin, but they have not specified any values of the series resistor. On page 192 of the datasheet, reference crystal characteristics, the ESR recommended is 50 ohms. I also understand that this does not require placing a 1Mohm resistor across the crystal terminals.

What resistor value should I place at the clock out pin? Is 510 ohms Ok, or any specific range?

Any guidance on how to arrive at a value of the series resistor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct situations.

The resistor is recommended if you are using an external clock **oscillator**. It should be near the oscillator module clock output pin rather than the chip and you could try a value such as 22Ω or 50Ω and fiddle with it a bit until the waveform looks good on your oscilloscope. After that, the value should be good enough for multiple units of production unless the layout or something else major changes. In this case, you leave X0 open (and you'll need one capacitor across the oscillator supply).

No resistor is recommended if you are using the internal clock oscillator with an external **crystal**. The 50Ω maximum ESR is a recommended characteristic of that crystal, it's not a discrete resistor. Along with the other values in the table. So if you can find a crystal with a maximum ESR of 30Ω you should be fine since 30Ω \$\le\$ 50Ω. The maximum ESR value should be shown in the crystal datasheet- if it isn't, don't buy it. If you want to use a crystal that does not meet those specifications, it gets a bit more complex, so it's best to stick to what is recommended. You'll need to calculate the two load capacitor values from the crystal load capacitance and stray/input capacitances (it is not taken directly from any datasheet).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So you're saying that a series resistor is not needed, if a crystal is used? For oscillators, the series resistor is required, right? Also, in your answer, you mentioned, 30Ω ≥50Ω. This is not true right?

Comment: Also, I checked the Evaluation boards of Microchip for these devices. https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/EVB-KSZ9477%20Evaluation%20Board%20Schematics.PDF & https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/EVB-KSZ9897%20Evaluation%20Board%20Schematics.pdf. Both of them use series resistors of 0ohms even with a crystal. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Newbie You got me before proofreading, fixed. Yes, series resistor is not need if a crystal with ESR < 50Ω, according to the checklist. The purpose of a series resistor with a crystal is to limit the drive power such that it does not overdrive the crystal. If you use an HC49 part with 1mW drive and reasonable ESR you'll never have a problem. With very small 100uW parts it might be, hence they have allowed for a resistor. It's not particularly easy to test this so using EVB part numbers is relatively safe.